# Replacing values in DF with quartile relative to others

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge CSV file with a bunch of metrics across item IDs that I'm trying to compare to one another, and I want to find the quartiles of every item within each metric and replace each actual number with its quartile ranking within the column.  An example is shown below for some dummy data.  If the metric has `NaN` values, I want to completely ignore them.  So for `Metric 2`, the quartiles would be based on the column having 10 values instead of 12.

```
ID     Metric 1     Metric 2     Metric 3
-----------------------------------------
1      10           4.8          155          
2      11           5.6          301
3      7            7.9          223
4      14           NaN          88
5      4            NaN          109
6      18           6.6          213
7      13           3.9          456
8      5            8.1          403
9      10           9.2          353
10     11           4.1          312
11     9            5.3          286
12     6            3.3          215


ID     Metric 1     Metric 2     Metric 3
-----------------------------------------
1      2            2            1          
2      3            3            3
3      2            4            2
4      4            NaN          1
5      1            NaN          1
6      4            3            2
7      4            1            4
8      1            4            4
9      2            4            4
10     3            2            3
11     2            2            3
12     1            1            2
```

I know there's a better way to do this in pandas than just looping through each cell, but I'm not quite sure how to approach it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the qcut method in Pandas with labels set. Here's an example:

create example data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'M1': randint(size=12, low=100, high = 500)})
df1['ID'] = df1.index
print df1.head()


    M1  ID
0  281   0
1  455   1
2  401   2
3  313   3
4  432   4
```

As long as there's no grouping, simply create a new variable using `qcut()`:

```
df1['M1Q'] = pd.qcut(df1.M1, 4, labels=[1,2,3,4])
print df1

     M1  ID M1Q
0   281   0   3
1   455   1   4
2   401   2   4
3   313   3   3
4   432   4   4
5   208   5   3
6   207   6   2
7   205   7   2
8   130   8   1
9   126   9   1
10  167  10   2
11  163  11   1
```

According to the help file qcut() does what you desire with nulls. But we might as well prove it to ourselves. So let's blow out some data and run again:

```
df1.M1.iloc[8:] = NaN
df1['M1Q'] = pd.qcut(df1.M1, 4, labels=[1,2,3,4])
print df1

     M1  ID M1Q
0   356   0   3
1   466   1   4
2   420   2   3
3   429   3   4
4   165   4   1
5   140   5   1
6   231   6   2
7   230   7   2
8   NaN   8 NaN
9   NaN   9 NaN
10  NaN  10 NaN
11  NaN  11 NaN
```

I think that looks like what you were after. Good luck!